# Can I still run an older non-supported, non-LTS Lubuntu?

Tags: updates, lubuntu, python, lts, sddm

How long can I run Lubuntu 18.10?

I have a program that was built by and for Python 2.7, which is no longer available in Lubuntu 19.04.

Source: https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fahcontrol/debian-stable-64bit/v7.5/fahcontrol_7.5.1-1_all.deb

The last version supported, is 18.10.

I wanted to know how long I can still run 18.10, and if I can install 18.10 from a USB stick a year from now, and download a year old updates on it?

The reason I ask, is I'm actually running Lubuntu, and Lubuntu 18.10 uses SDDM, which looks much more appealing to me than LightDM. I just don't want to go back to 18.04.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10 release-upgrades to 19.04 which is it's intended support path. Why do you not want to take that intended route when 18.10 reaches EOL on the 18th? (tomorrow).   No your 18.10 won't blow up on the 19th, and you can still use it for as longer as your hardware works, however without security updates, it could be a security risk if connected to the web, or files are transferred using other means (the risk depends on what you do, what you transfer etc).

Comment: Is your box running x86/i386/i686?

Comment: Like mentioned above, the upgrade to Ubuntu 19 disables the program that runs on Python 2.7. Python 2.7 dependencies no longer work in Ubuntu 19.

Comment: If your reason for preferring 19.04 over 18.04 is just the display manager, then that's a pity. Anyway, it's not uncommon for projects to support LTS releases only.

Comment: `sddm` is available on 18.04 too (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=sddm)

Comment: For some reason converting to SDDM, every program is duplicated in the taskbar.
I presume SDDM uses different programs and program names than LightDM.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ubuntu is one thing…

Lubuntu 18.10 release-upgrades to 19.04 which is it's intended support path. Why do you not want to take that intended route when 18.10 reaches EOL on the 18th? (tomorrow).

No your 18.10 won't blow up on the 19th, and you can still use it for as longer as your hardware works, however without security updates, it could be a security risk if connected to the web, or files are transferred using other means (the risk depends on what you do, what you transfer etc).

Yes you can still use the 18.10 install media to install ten years from now, however some functions may not work (eg. you may have hardware that requires the addition of packages which are grabbed from the web; currently they are available at http://archive.ubuntu.com/, however soon they'll be moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com and thus the installer won't find them resulting in errors). You won't notice this if you have very basic hardware (that the install media can cope with), but either way - due to no security updates you should instead be asking yourself why you want do this this? and should you!?

Lubuntu 18.10's intended upgrade path was to 19.04 are covered in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes  (the *Upgrading from 18.10* section) however there is a caveat that i386/686 isn't possible there.

#### …but Python is another

The original EOL date for Python 2.7 was in 2015. They decided to move it out a few years, but only until next year. That means that this program you have will also be a potential security risk in short order.

Perhaps the best solution might be porting the program to Python 3. With [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), you should find this to be a relatively simple task.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the question. The program which depends on Python 2.7 dependencies doesn't work in Ubuntu/Lubuntu 19.

As for porting it, yea right. Good luck with that. I don't even understand the conversion page, let alone how to successfully operate the program.

The program is:
https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fahcontrol/debian-stable-64bit/v7.5/fahcontrol_7.5.1-1_all.deb

I'm not sure it can just be converted like that.

Comment: I read the question quite clearly, thus the segment of the answer concerning Python. You should probably try converting it, or barring your comfortability with that, talk to the developers of that program. Python 2.7 is doomed. No distro will be providing it in short order. And I'm sure anything at Folding@Home requires the Internet, which will open you up to security risks if you use an old distro.